# Dockerized python app versus executable in production

Tags: python, docker, deployment, exe, cx-freeze

We have a python-based application deployed as a docker image on Azure production environment.
We use Azure DevOps Pipeline Release to deploy it.
Ordinary usage of the application is through batch and if needed on-demand.
The application uses on-prem databases and environment variables, it inputs data, calculates some values and provides results either through depositing files in blobs or updating the database.

Now, we've been asked to move the app on premise (but still using Azure DevOps to deploy).
However, we've been challenged on the use of docker.
Docker allows us to make the application portable, isolated, easy to deploy and somehow scalable. But for the client, the python-based app doesn't need to be dockerised and should only be packaged to be a **.exe** (using a tool like cx_freeze) to be run on the on-prem server.

I've never encountered such use on production and would like to know if anyone experienced it. What would be the pro and cons of the two approaches, in terms of development, deployment, maintainability?

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.